# When I register any user but remember_token() Always Null In Db During Insertion using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to register any user but remember_token() Always Null In Db During Insertion how to fix it ?

```
     [User table][1]
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/94WbY.png
```

**html view**

```
                <form action="{{url('Register/action')}}" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-12">Register</button>
                </form>
```

**controller**

```
                    public function registeraction(Request $request)
                    {
                    $this->validate($request,[
                   'name'=>'Required',             
                   'email' => 'Required',
                   'password' => 'Required',]);
                    $user = User::create(request(['name', 'email', 'password']));
                    if($user)
                    {
                    return redirect('/login');
                    }
                    }
```

**Route**

```
              Route::get('Register','CheckController@register');
              Route::post('Register/action','CheckController@registeraction');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `remember_me` field is only populated when a user is logged in with the "remember me" option for `Auth::attempt` enabled.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#remembering-users

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], true)
```

Without the `true` there, it'll stay `null`, and it also won't be filled in when you *create* a user, just when you *log them in*.

Comment: @zubairmukhtar Show us your existing login controller code. You've shown registration, but that's not really relevant to your issue.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwXdE.png  please check login controller

Comment: @zubairmukhtar So, add `true` as the second argument to your `Auth::attempt` call, as my answer advises.

Comment: i have used Auth:attempt  but remember_token is not generating  into db 
please check code    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kXUS.png